# Repeat a set of rows (dataframe) and adding a string to each set

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, one have all data to be repeated to create a new DataFrame but each time it is repeated, a column has to change its values using the letter from another DataFrame:

`DF1
     t1   t2   t3  t4
 0   ABC  0   A   1950
 1   CDE  1   A   1950`

and

`DF2
    [P,Q,R]`

I want to get:

`DF0
     t1   t2   t3  t4
 0   ABC  0   A   1950-P
 1   CDE  1   A   1950-P
 2   XYZ  1   B   1954-Q
 3   123  1   C   1954-Q
 4   ABC  0   A   1950-R
 5   CDE  1   A   1950-R`

I have tried  :

```
TMP = pd.DataFrame()
DF0 = pd.DataFrame()

TMP = DF1['t4']
DF1['t4'] = TMP + ' ' + DF2[0]
DF0 = DF0.append(DF1)

TMP = DF1['t4']
DF1['t4'] = TMP + ' ' + DF2[0]
DF0 = DF0.append(DF1)
```

but P is still in the second iteration and third, something like this:

```
1   CDE  1   A   1950-P
2   XYZ  1   B   1954-P-Q
```

Comment: 2nd dataframe looks like a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cross join with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+) for repat lists values:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['P','Q','R']]})
print (df2)
         col
0  [P, Q, R]

df2 = df2.explode('col')
print (df2)
  col
0   P
0   Q
0   R
df = df1.assign(a=1).merge(df2.assign(a=1), on='a')
df['t4'] = df['t4'].astype(str) + '-' + df['col']
print (df)
    t1  t2 t3      t4  a col
0  ABC   0  A  1950-P  1   P
1  ABC   0  A  1950-Q  1   Q
2  ABC   0  A  1950-R  1   R
3  CDE   1  A  1950-P  1   P
4  CDE   1  A  1950-Q  1   Q
5  CDE   1  A  1950-R  1   R
```